# Tooltip is not displayed under current mouse position EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I try to run this sample from sencha extjs site. The pie chart is rendered, but the tooltip is not rendered under the current mouse's position. It's rendered either top left or bottom left of the page. Has anyone encountered this issue and how to fix it?

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['name', 'data'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'metric one',   'data': 10 },
        { 'name': 'metric two',   'data':  7 },
        { 'name': 'metric three', 'data':  5 },
        { 'name': 'metric four',  'data':  2 },
        { 'name': 'metric five',  'data': 27 }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: 'chart',
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    theme: 'Base:gradients',
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        angleField: 'data',
        showInLegend: true,
        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 140,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                // calculate and display percentage on hover
                var total = 0;
                store.each(function(rec) {
                    total += rec.get('data');
                });
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('name') + ': ' + Math.round(storeItem.get('data') / total * 100) + '%');
            }
        },
        highlight: {
            segment: {
                margin: 20
            }
        },
        label: {
            field: 'name',
            display: 'rotate',
            contrast: true,
            font: '18px Arial'
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: were you able to get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Example is working fine on sencha website with ExtJS version 4.1.3 here:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/charts/Pie.html

Please provide more details about which version of sencha ExtJS you are using and browser details so that someone can help. It may be browser specific issue.